# Autodesk Maya api - import geometry

Tags: python, api, maya, mel

Hi I am trying to create an API in Maya to load a custom file format then read in data to create vertices.

My overall goal is to create vertices from data in a file then convert to polygons.

Any help would be appreciated.

Mark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually when people talk about "API" in maya they are referring to [OpenMaya](http://docs.autodesk.com/MAYAUL/2014/ENU/Maya-API-Documentation/index.html), which is a Python wrapper for the C++ API that Maya exposes to plugin developers.  There are actually two versions of this in recent Mayas:

1. [OpenMaya 1.0](http://docs.autodesk.com/MAYAUL/2014/ENU/Maya-API-Documentation/index.html)
2. [OpenMaya 2.0](http://docs.autodesk.com/MAYAUL/2014/ENU/Maya-API-Documentation/index.html)

where the 2.0 version is more 'pythonic' but also less mature and less full featured.  Both of these are included with any Maya installation - you can access them with standard python imports from the Maya script listener.

For the problem you are describing you can use the API like so:

```
def create(verts, faces, merge=True):
    '''
    Given a list of vertices (iterables of floats) and a list of faces (iterable of integer vert indices),
    creates and returns a maya Mesh
    '''

    cmds.select(cl=True)  
    outputMesh = OpenMaya.MObject()

    numFaces = len(faces)
    numVertices = len(verts)

    # point array of plane vertex local positions
    points = OpenMaya.MFloatPointArray()
    for eachVt in verts:
        p = OpenMaya.MFloatPoint(eachVt[0], eachVt[1], eachVt[2])
        points.append(p)

    # vertex connections per poly face in one array of indexs into point array given above
    faceConnects = OpenMaya.MIntArray()
    for eachFace in faces:
        for eachCorner in eachFace:
            faceConnects.append(eachCorner)

    # an array to hold the total number of vertices that each face has
    faceCounts = OpenMaya.MIntArray()
    for c in range(0, numFaces, 1):
        faceCounts.append(3)

    # create mesh object using arrays above and get name of new mesh
    meshFS = OpenMaya.MFnMesh()
    newMesh = meshFS.create(numVertices, numFaces, points, faceCounts, faceConnects, outputMesh)
    nodeName = meshFS.name()
    cmds.sets(nodeName, add='initialShadingGroup')  
    cmds.select(nodeName)  
    meshFS.updateSurface()
    # this is useful because it deletes stray vertices (ie, those not used in any faces)
    if merge:
        cmds.polyMergeVertex(nodeName, ch=0)
    meshFS.updateSurface()
    return nodeName
```

However this example calls the API directly from python without wrapping it in an API command shell, so it can't be undone using conventional undo methods. To turn it into a full-fledged operation with Undo support you need to make this function part of an [MPXCommand](http://docs.autodesk.com/MAYAUL/2014/ENU/Maya-API-Documentation/index.html).  As you can see using the 1.0 OpenMaya API from Python is a bit cumbersome because it involves creating proxies for C++ data types which Python does not support natively, so it may be very complicated if you're not familiar with both languages and Maya.  I don't have enough experience with the 2.0 API to know if it is a significant improvement, but word-on-the-street says it's not very complete yet.

If you are not worried about speed you can just use the regular [`maya.cmds`](http://help.autodesk.com/view/MAYAUL/2015/ENU/) module to create geometry using the same functions an artist would use to make the geometry by hand. Here's simple example:

```
verts = [(0,0,0), (0,1,0), (1,0,0), (1,1,1)]
faces = [(0,1,2),(1,2,3)]

def create_geometry(verts, faces):    
   cmds.constructionHistory(tgl = 'off')
   results = []
   for f in faces:
       points = [verts[i] for i in f]
       results += cmds.polyCreateFacet( p = points, ch = 0)
   cmds.polyUnite(results, ch=0)
   cmds.polyMergeVertex(d=0, ch=0)
   cmds.constructionHistory(tgl = 'on')


create_geometry(verts, faces)
```

As you can see this method is significantly simpler to write, but it's also much slower.  The right way for you depends on your needs.  If you can just distribute a python script, the second method is easier. If you want to create a traditional plugin that creates a full-fledged maya file translator or new MEL command you'll have to use the MPXCommand route.

Comment: Hi Thank you. But what I was thinking is. Maya to read in a file and iterate through the file. I was thinking of creating a .DXF importer so I can convert the lines to curves then to polygons. so I can extrude them. So it would read in the data from the file and then I can create a 3d world from the drawings. I know there is allready a importer for .DWG and .DXF but I would like to create my own plugin.

Comment: The basic strategy question is the same: you can do the same import-and-create algorithm in plain maya.cmds or using OpenMaya; the former is easier and slower, the latter is harder and more error prone but faster.  Creating curves is almost the same as creating polys: the API command  will be different (in maya.cmds its `cmds.curve(p = your-list-of-points-here, d= curve-degree`). Re-implementing the DXF importer is a significant chunk of work, since DXF is an old and loose standard.... Iterating over imported geometry is easy with `cmds.ls` or the API

Comment: Oh ok. So is that first example reading in a file's data and creating geometry? Ideally I wanted to create a .DWG file importer. So if I iterate over a .dwg file can I call just the lines from the file and draw them into Maya?

Comment: Both examples are for _creating_ geometry, since I was not clear on what format you were reading.  DWG import should be included in the default Maya DXF imported. From there you can use regular maya commands to loop over the scene and modify it as needed. You can figure out the right sequence of actions by doing some of it manually in an imported file and watching what commands are issued by Maya in the script listener as you work,

Comment: You may find this useful: http://area.autodesk.com/blogs/stevenr/direct_connect_visualizing_cad_data_in_maya

Comment: My main objective is to create the actual importer as a plugin and my secondary goal is to convert the lines to polygons. I am just not quite sure how to go about it.

Comment: You'll need to start here if you want to make a canonical maya importer: http://docs.autodesk.com/MAYAUL/2014/ENU/Maya-API-Documentation/index.html and then http://docs.autodesk.com/MAYAUL/2014/ENU/Maya-API-Documentation/index.html.  

Warning: it's a non-trivial amount of work

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. could you point me in what way I should do it please.

Comment: Would it be the file translator part.

Comment: First link is the basics of writing plugins with the OpenMaya API; second is specific to file translators. I'd do them in order because Maya has some unusual requirements for making a plugin work properly so you should learn the API basics before getting into specifics. You might want to try this book to get rollinghttp://techartsurvival.blogspot.com/p/bookstore.html

Comment: Thank you for all your help I really appreciate it. I find it hard learning a new language.